# Spring JMS : Configure Multi Consumer client

Tags: jms, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I am developing a Spring JMS based client, which connects to an IBM MQ.

This part is working fine !!

**Scenario:**

The MQ client can get a request from multiple Spring "@Components". Considering, JMSTemplate's "send" and "receive" are completely different methods -

**Question:**

How do we co-relate the response from component-one to only its request ? e.g.

A sends request-A

B sends request-B

How will SpringListener know to respond the response-A to A, and response-B to B ?

Does spring provide an out of box functionality to handle such a scenario ?

Thanks in advance !!

**Sample Listener :**

```
public class MessageReceiver implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {

        if(message instanceof TextMessage){
            System.out.println(message.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample Sender :**

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = (JmsTemplate)context.getBean("jmsTemplate");

        jmsTemplate.send(s -> s.createTextMessage("TestingAMQ"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this to be the approach of 'setProperty' -

https://codedependents.com/2010/03/04/synchronous-request-response-with-activemq-and-spring/

Answer (score 1):

based on the `JMSReplyTo` header you can do it with
`JmsTemplate.sendAndReceive` for the sender

and in the listener side by

```
    public class MessageReceiver implements MessageListener {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
            jmsTemplate.send(message.getJMSReplyTo(), s -> s.createTextMessage("TestingAMQ"));
            if(message instanceof TextMessage){
                System.out.println(message.toString());
            }
        }
   }
```

**OR**

By setting a Message property in the sender side by `Message.setStringProperty` and use selectors in the listener or conditional response based on the StringProperty.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html#sendAndReceive-org.springframework.jms.core.MessageCreator-

Comment: The method "sendAndReceive" creates a temporary Queue to respond ( per the jmsTemplate documentation ). "Message.setStringProperty" seems like a good idea ... but wouldn't the method have to be synchronized ? Unless the method is synchronized - a new thread might change the 'property' value in the method.

Comment: Another option could be to make - send + receive transactional. Although, I am not sure how this might be implemented.

Comment: Send a message and receive the reply from the specified destination.( per the jmsTemplate documentation ) since you pass it as a parameter to the sendAndReceive method, destination can be of any type and created before

Comment: why a new thread might change the 'property' value in the method ? your message is created and sent by only one thread

Comment: Thanks @Hassen Bennour .... I found some a link with the 'setProperty' approach you suggested !

Comment: you are welcome, do not forget to check to remove it from unanswered queue